# list iteration won't work as function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I am trying to iterate through a list and pass each of the values to a function. The function works fine if I type each of the list values manually. I used console.log to ensure that cars[x] is returning proper values. The problem is at the very end with the line var worthALook......

I'm brand new to JS and I'm trying to understand what is going on.

```
function prequal(car){
    if (car.mileage > 100000){
        return false;
    } else if (car.year > 1960){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

let taxi = {
    make: "Webville Motors",
    model: "Taxi",
    year: 1955,
    color: "yellow",
    passengers: 4,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 281341
}

let cadi = {
    make: "GM",
    model: "Cadillac",
    year: 1955,
    color: "tan",
    passengers: 5,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 12892
}

let fiat = {
    make: "Fiat",
    model: "500",
    year: 1977,
    color: "Medium Blue",
    passgengers: 2,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 88000
}

let chevy = {
    make: "Chevrolet",
    model: "Bel Air",
    year: 1957,
    color: "red",
    passgengers: 2,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 1021
}
cars = ["taxi", "cadi", "fiat", "chevy"]


for ( x=0; x < cars.length; x++){
    console.log(cars[x]);
    var worthALook = prequal(cars[x]);

    if (worthALook){
        console.log("Your gotta check out this " + cars[x]);
    }else {
        console.log("You should really pass on the " + cars[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make an object of car objects instead of standalone variables, then you'll be able to use bracket notation to look them up. eg `carData[cars[i]]`

Comment: Would that look like this carData={fiat:{make:"Fiat", model:50......}?

Comment: Yep, like that - then you can look up the appropriate sub-object with bracket notation when given a string like `fiat`.